# Conditionally coping data from one sheet to multiple sheet using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a code to copy data from one sheet to other sheets only if some conditions are met with. In this code the one part that is delete the data before copying data is working perfectly but  second part i.e. copying data is not working. The code is as below:-

Any prompt help shall be appreciated

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cl As Range
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim RowEmpCrnt As Long
Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long
Dim WshtEmp As Worksheet

Set WshtEmp = Sheets("Employee Data")
Set Rng = WshtEmp.UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "" 'string1 to look for should be empty
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for should be empty
Sheets("Updated").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("AK").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Working"s are in column AV and blank cells are in column AK.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "AK" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Updated
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "," 'string1 to look for should be non empty
str2 = "Transferred" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Transferred").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("AK").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Transferred"s are in column AV and blank cells are in column AK.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "AK" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Transferred
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Transferred").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Transferred").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Executive" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Executive").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Executive"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Executive
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Executive").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Executive").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl

Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Supervisior" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Supervisior"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Supervisior
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Workmen" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Workmen").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Workmen"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Supervisior
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Workmen").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Workmen").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a random guess - if you change your code from that `Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))` to that `Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))` everywhere would it work? And furthermore, can you simply remove the useless code of the app and summarize the parts that do not work?

Comment: Thanks for editing but this is not working